# How do i display data passed from viewbag in controller to view

Tags: c#, linq, model-view-controller, .net-core, viewbag

I have tried to display using @(foreach var x in viewbag.data2) loop in view

```
 var data = from c in _context.Posts
                       join p in _context.PostViewCount on c.Id equals p.PostId
                       select new
                       {
                           posts = c,
                           p.Count,
                           c.Title,
                           p.PostId

                       };
            var dat = data.OrderByDescending(x=>x.Count).ToList();
            ViewBag.data2 = dat;
```

I m getting invalid operation exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got your syntax a little wrong.

it should be:

```
@foreach(var x in ViewBag.data2){

    @x.Count
    @x.Title

}
```

---

Edit: As there seems to be a little bit of confusion with `dynamic` types. This example shows how to use a defined model..

Create a class for your data rather than using an anonymous object.

```
public class PostsModel
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
    // etc...
}
```

Modify your query...

```
var data = from c in _context.Posts
                   join p in _context.PostViewCount on c.Id equals p.PostId
                   select new PostsModel
                   {
                       Count = p.Count,
                       Title = c.Title,
                       // etc...
                   };
        var dat = data.OrderByDescending(x=>x.Count).ToList();
        ViewBag.data2 = dat;
```

Then just cast your `Viewbag` variable to the right type...

```
@foreach(PostsModel x in ((IEnumerable<PostsModel>)ViewBag.data2)){

    @x.Count
    @x.Title

}
```

You might have to import the right namespace to your view by using: `@using <namespace>`

Comment: Thank You i have tried but still no luck foreach (var x in ViewBag.data2 )
 {
  
  @x.Title
 }

Comment: @GauravAcharya Explain what no luck means. I have this running in a project as we speak.

Comment: I m getting exception "RuntimeBinderException: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Title'   "

Comment: @GauravAcharya see the edit, I think you're struggling to work with anonymous types, just use a model instead to save yourself from problems such as this. This answer is already a tutorial so I won't be updating this any further.

Comment: You need to write in your view like @x.'your property name'

Answer (score -1):

To access viewbag write the below code in your view
@ViewBag.data2

It will give you the data.

And place the debugger on it. You will understand the rest.

Comment: Im getting this in my view System.Collections.Generic.List`1[<>f__AnonymousType3`4[PremiumAccount.Post,System.Int32,System.String,System.Int32]]